# Newbie from 3DS Max. Ignore Backfacing ? Limit Selection to Visible ? 2.80?

Tags: edit-mode

Veteran user of 3DS Max, I'm one day into learning Blender 2.80 but am struggling with selecting ALL faces of an object including those which are backfacing.

My searching has mentioned that there is a Limit Selction to Visible which needs to be unchecked but where is that in Blender 2.80 ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I guess what you're looking for is this option, *Show whole scene transparent*, <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to activate in whatever shading mode you are:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I did find that but kept looking for the Limit Selection to Visible..

Comment: this is the new Limit Selection to Visible  ;)